# What's wrong in my approach in evaluating $\cos^{-1}(\cos\ 10)$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

**The Question** 
$\large\cos^{-1}(\cos 10)$
[image: Initial angle]

**My Approach**
$\large\cos^{-1}(\cos\ (10-2\pi))$ As $2\pi$ is the period of $\cos x.$ Now our angle is-
[image: Our angle now]
Now we know that for $\large\cos^{-1}(\cos x) = x$, $\large x\ \epsilon\ [0,\pi]$ but currently our $\large x$ **is in the 3rd quadrant, we need to get it into 1st or 2nd quadrant.** Therefore let us subtract $\large \pi$ from our current angle i.e $\large 10-2\pi$ 
$\large\cos^{-1}(\cos\ -((10-2\pi)-\pi))$ Now you must be wondering why did I put this minus sign, w.k.t $\large \cos x$ is -ve in third quadrant, by subtracting $\large \pi$ we brought it into 1st quadrant and $\large \cos x$ is +ve in 1st quad, so to compensate that I have put a minus sign.
[image: Our final angle]
Now its within range so we can use $\large\cos^{-1}(\cos x) = x$. 
So Final answer $\large -((10-2\pi)-\pi)$ = $\large 3\pi - 10$
But this answer is wrong and the correct answer is $\large 4\pi - 10$.
They have used the property $\large \cos\  (\pi - \theta) = \cos\  (\pi + \theta)$ But why my approach is wrong?
Kindly help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120968/discussion-on-question-by-vyom-yadav-whats-wrong-in-my-approach-in-evaluating).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is in the third quadrant, its symmetric w.r.t. the $x$-axis is in the second quadrant, and has the same cosine. This symmetric point has curvilinear abscissa $6\pi - x$, as you've found. To determine the value which is represented by the same point on the trigonometric circle, let's just make some elementary manipulations on inequalities.

If $x=10$ˆ, we have $3\pi < x <\dfrac{7\pi}2$, so
\begin{align}
&&\frac{5\pi}2 &<6\pi -x< 3\pi  \\[1ex]
&\llap{\text{whence}}\qquad& \frac \pi 2 &<(6\pi-x)-2\pi=4\pi -x <\pi&&\qquad
\end{align}
The solution follows.

Comment: I edited the question and mentioned what I was thinking, kindly review and help once.

Comment: Can you point out which step is wrong, I have justified every step that I have done. Which one is wrong and why?

Comment: @VyomYadav: There's an error at the end –  changing  the sign doesn't mean the arc will be in the second quadrant, but in the fourth, since you obtained an arc in the first quadrant, and changing the sign corresponds to a symmetry w.r.t. the $x$-axis. You should have made a symmetry w.r.y=t. the $y$-axis, i.e. replace the arc $x$ with $\pi-x$.

Comment: Can you explain a bit or some good read, I think I don't know about this topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helpful, your comment cleared all my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $10^c$ means 10 radians. 
$\pi^c=180^o\implies 1^c \sim57^o\implies 10^c\sim 570^o$
$\cos 10 =\cos (10-2\pi)=-\cos(10-3\pi)=\cos (\pi-(10-3\pi))$
$\arccos(\cos 10)=4\pi-10$ 
Your answer turns out to be wrong as $\arccos(\cos x)=x$ when $x\in [0,\pi]$. Note that $3\pi-10\notin [0,\pi]$.

Comment: I removed c for clarity from the question

Comment: @VyomYadav: I hope this answers your question.

Comment: The solution is fine, I also have it but I wanted to know why my approach is wrong.

Comment: @VyomYadav: Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Yes I know my answer is wrong as it is not in the range, but where is the problem in my solution while I change the angle. I can subtract $\pi$ from cos and compensate it by putting a - sign if the sign changes while changing the quadrant. Please also see the pictures I attached while doing my steps, where I went wrong?

Comment: I can add the picture instead of links but my rep is 1 short.

Comment: @VyomYadav: Your final angle should be in 4th quadrant but in the image you have wrongly put it in 1st quad. That’s the problem. Note that $-10+3\pi\sim -30^o$

Comment: But after removing $2\pi$ it came to 3rd quad and if I remove $\pi$ from 3rd quad I should land in 1st why that is not happening?

Comment: @VyomYadav: Note minus sign. Angle of 1st quad is multiplied by $-1$ and this multiplication sends it to 4th quad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120910/discussion-between-vyom-yadav-and-koro).

Answer (score 1):

Note
$$
\cos^{-1}(\cos(x)) =\begin{cases}
2\pi n +x\in (0,\frac\pi2)\>\>\>x \text{ in 1st quadrant}\\
2\pi n +x\in (\frac\pi2,\pi) \>\>\>x \text{ in 2nd quadrant}\\
2\pi n -x\in (\frac\pi2,\pi) \>\>\>x \text{ in 3rd quadrant}\\
  2\pi n -x\in (0,\frac\pi2)\>\>\>x \text{ in 4th quadrant}\\
\end{cases}$$

In particular, if  $x$ is in the 3rd quadrant

$$\cos^{-1}(\cos(x)) = 
\cos^{-1}(-|\cos(x)|) 
=  \pi -\cos^{-1}(|\cos(x)|)\\
= \pi -\cos^{-1}(\cos(\pi+ x-2\pi n))
=2\pi n -x\in (\frac\pi2,\pi)$$

Thus, for $x=10$ in the 3rd quadrant, let $n=2$ to obtain

$$\cos^{-1} (\cos(10))= 4\pi -10\in (\frac\pi2,\pi)
$$

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct, but I wan't to know whats the fault in my approach?

Comment: I edited the question and mentioned what I was thinking, kindly review and help once.

Comment: @VyomYadav - you need to use $\cos^{-1}x= \pi - \cos^{-1}|x| $ for $-1<x<0$ in your 3rd step

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $\arccos(\cos(x)) =x$ only if $x \in [0,\pi]$. Note that arccos(x) is inverse of cos(x).

Thus, we need to get $10$ into that range. We can subtract periods to get $10-4\pi$, but this is a negative number $\approx -2$, not in the range, which was your mistake. So, we can use the identity that $\cos(x) = \cos(-x)$, so $\cos(10-4\pi) = \cos(4\pi-10)$. $4\pi - 10$ is in range, so we are good there. Now, we need to calculate $\arccos(\cos(4\pi-10))$. However, since $4\pi - 10 \approx 2.5$, which is in the range $[0,\pi]$, we know that $\arccos(\cos(4\pi-10))$ is just $4\pi-10$.

Comment: I edited the question and mentioned what I was thinking, kindly review and help once.

Answer (score 1):

The angle $\theta$ that you're looking for corresponds to the point (on the unit circle) directly above the black dot in your second drawing, which corresponds to the angle $10-2\pi$. The average of these two angles is $\pi$, so from

$${1\over2}(\theta+(10-2\pi))=\pi$$

we find $\theta=4\pi-10$.